# JSONObject in Spring MVC - SEVERE Context initialization failed error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm getting an error when I try to instatiate JSONObject:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'budgetController' defined in file [C:\Users\yqb18196\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Budget\WEB-INF\classes\biz\martyn\budget\controller\BudgetController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [biz.martyn.budget.controller.BudgetController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
...
```

Here is where the error is occuring:

```
public class ApiClient {

    ...

    public void requestData() {

        String str = "{}";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str); // <-- error
        // ...
    }
}
```

It is called from a Spring MVC controller, if that matters:

```
@Controller
public class BudgetController {

    public BudgetController() {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        apiClient.requestData();

    }
...
```

I've looked at umpteen tutorials on how to use JSONObject and I can't see exactly how I'm using it incorrectly, but then I am newish to Java so might be something else.

Comment: try to change BudgetController constructor to method annotated with @PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
   //do your stuff
}
this annotation helps to run this method after BudgetController bean is initialized

Comment: Hi. No, still getting the error message.

Comment: you can check this repository https://github.com/ishikawayoshi/so-example you can run this example and check log.